# How to Adjust Flutter DropdownButton Width Dynamically Based on Selected Item?

Tags: android, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm working on a Flutter app and I'm trying to create a `DropdownButton` that adjusts its width based on the length of the selected item's text. I want the dropdown to be as wide as the selected item and not the widest item in the list. This functionality is similar to a native HTML `select` element where the width is dynamically sized to the currently selected option.

Here's a simplified version of my current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? selectedValue;
  final List<String> options = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Fig'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
            value: selectedValue,
            items: options.map((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              setState(() {
                selectedValue = newValue;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The dropdown always takes the width of the widest item in the list. However, I want the dropdown to fit the width of the selected item only, similar to the behavior shown in this

[image]

I tried using ButtonTheme with alignedDropdown: true and setting isDense: true on the DropdownButton, but it did not produce the desired result.

Is it actually possible to have a DropdownButton in Flutter that auto-adjusts its width based on the selected item? If so, how can I achieve this behavior?

Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
Center(
        child: ColoredBox(
          color: Colors.purple.shade100,
          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton<String>(

              /// **********
              isExpanded: false,
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
              /// **********

              value: selectedValue,
              items: options.map((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedValue = newValue;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Not worked, with your solution , all i got is a dropdown with width matching the screen width .

Comment: Try this answer

Comment: "  final List<String> options = ['Apple', 'Bananaaaaaaaaaaafgdfgfdgfdgdfg', 'Cherry', 'Fig'];
" test with these strings,

Comment: Ok, I understood your problem. Wait sec

Comment: I tried everything that I know but I didn't find any solution.
DropDownButton take width which is biggest , it's seems really broken.

Comment: Yes,Same here, that is why i posted it on stackoverflow